# Exercise with a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, document.write

I need for an university exercise to display onscreen with a document.write the tree below using a kind of loop:

[image: tree]

I used at the beginning a for loop but i printed only the first row... someone can help me?

This is what I tried:

```
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
for (var i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) { 
    if (numbers [i] == 0) { 
        document.write(" * </br>"); 
    } 
    if (numbers [i] == 1) {
        document.write(" *** </br>"); 
    }
    if (numbers [i] == 2) {
        document.write(" ****** </br>"); 
    } 
    if (numbers [i] == 3) {
        document.write(" ******* </br>"); }
    if (numbers [i] == 4) { 
        document.write("********* </br>"); 
    }
    return 
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Fixed your image for you ;)

Comment: Anypancake, please show the actual code you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow... please read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) particularly the section regarding [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We are not a code writing service, and (as Niet has already highlighted) we expect people to show what they have already tried

Comment: I'm pretty a newbie of javascript and it was my first lesson of that.

my code was (i know it's wrong):

    var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 

for (var i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers [i] == 0)
    {   
        document.write("   * </br>");
    }
    if (numbers [i] == 1)
    {
        document.write("   *** </br>");
    }
    if (numbers [i] == 2)
    {
        document.write("  ****** </br>");
    }
    if (numbers [i] == 3)
    {
        document.write(" ******* </br>");
    }
    if (numbers [i] == 4)
    {
        document.write("********* </br>");
    }
    return
}

Comment: The main problem with your attempt is that it's hard-coded.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to give you a "golfed-ish" (goldfish? should this be a thing?) version of the code. In other words, the smallest, most obscure code I can think of to accomplish the task. You *should not use this*, because your teacher will undoubtedly ask you what it means and you won't know, but I'm bored XD

```
var size = 5;
document.write("<center>"+Array.apply(0,new Array(size)).map(function(_,i) {return new Array((i+1)*2).join(" * ");}).join("<br>")+"</center>");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cnc7p/)

As I said, don't use this :p

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for you ...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

document.write("<center>"); //write a center tag to make sure the pyramid displays correctly(try it without this step to see what happens)
for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) //a loop, this counts from 0 to 10 (how many rows of stars)
{
    for(var x = 0; x <= i; x++)// a loop, counting from 0 to whatever value i is currently on
    {
        document.write("*");//write a * character
    }
    document.write("<br/>"); //write a br tag, meaning new line, after every star in the row has been created
}
document.write("</center>"); //close the center tag, opened at the beginning

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: -buzzer- WRONG. Prints a triangle with 2 stars on the second row. 3 expected.

Comment: Add this to for loop: if(x==2){x++;}

Comment: @phpBud So you are aware you are giving wrong code to a newbie?

Comment: @nicael Your "addition" makes it worse.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol now?

Comment: Thank you @phpBud, your code it's the most understandable for me!

Comment: I know that's why i write.. may of user write the tuffest code .. but i beleave to understandable code make it simple so that it can better be modified by the other accordingly in comparison of complex one..

Comment: Starting with your code, for having the exact exercise (3 stars second row, 5 in third....) how can i do? @phpBud

Answer (score 1):

```html
<pre><script>
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (var c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
    if (Math.abs(4 - c) <= i)
      document.write("*");
    else
      document.write(" ");
  }
  document.write("<br />");
}
</script></pre>
```

It is a simple version with document.write(). The only complicated thing is Math.abs which gives the distance from the middle.

PS: watch out for magic numbers

Answer (score 1):

Adds spaces and fully extendable

```
function pyramid(lines, char) {
    var start = 2,html = '<pre>';
    for (var i=lines; i--;) {
        html += new Array(Math.floor(i+1)).join(' ') + new Array((start=start+2)-2).join(char) + '<br />';
    }
    return html + '</pre>';
}

document.write( pyramid(5, '*') );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5UJ89/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function pyramidStar(n) {
  var str = "";
  for(var i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    for(var j=1; j<=n-i; j++) {
      str += "   ";
    }
    for(var k=n-i+1; k<n+i; k++) {
      str += "*  ";
    }
    for(var m=n+i; m<=2*n-1; m++) {
      str += "   ";
    }
    str += "\n";
  }
  return str;
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = pyramidStar(9);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Another way of printing pyramid of stars.

Answer (score 0):

```
function star(n) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (var j = i; j < n; j++) {
            document.write("-");
        }
        for (var k = 1; k <= (2 * i) - 1; k++) {
            document.write("*");
        }
        document.write("<br/>");
    }

}
```

//function calling

> star(9);