# create piramid when click a button

Tags: javascript

i want to create a piramid from for loop.

my current result is like this

[image]

i want to be like this

[image]

```
<button id="piramid" onclick="piramid()">test</button>
```

heres the code

https://jsfiddle.net/k22bf4o4/

how to loop so the result will become like the last image?
thank  you for your time

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: i update the description

Comment: this looks like homework. you should solve it on your own!

Comment: we're not here to do your work for you

Comment: I understand you are a "beginner" like I once was. Let me give you some advice, try building your pyramid using pure html en css first. Than switch to javascript!

Comment: i even look at this [link]http://jsfiddle.net/5UJ89/1/ and this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567463/exercise-with-a-loop-in-javascript , i just try to figure out how to make the piramid without change the code to much,(copy paste). but thank you for your help.

Comment: https://codepen.io/android5803/pen/weZYGg Maybe a headstart?

Answer (score 0):

The previous commenters are right that you should not post your homework on StackOverflow. That said, it's a fun excercise that I wanted to do for myself.

For the numbers, I see now that the numbers originate from pyramids of two rows high, that are turned upside down. E.g. take the third row from the top: 1 + 2 = 3 where the 3 will be the top of the upside down pyramid with base row 1 and 2 (the row above the row with 3). Once you see that, it's up to you or somebody else on SO to write code for it.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pyramid</title>
</head>

<body></body>

<script src="pyramid.js"></script>

</html>
```

pyramid.js

```
let blockWidth = 20,
    blockHeight = 20,
    blockCountBaseRow = 10,
    blockOffset = blockWidth / 2;
let drawSurfaceWidth = blockWidth * blockCountBaseRow,
    drawSurfaceHeight = blockHeight * blockCountBaseRow,
    drawSurfaceCenter = drawSurfaceWidth / 2;

createDrawingSurface();
drawPyramid();

function createDrawingSurface() {
    let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0);
    body.innerHTML += '<div id="drawingSurface" style="' +
        'position:absolute;' +
        'width:' + drawSurfaceWidth + 'px;' +
        'height:' + drawSurfaceHeight + 'px;' +
        'background:#EEE;">' +
        '</div>';
}

function drawPyramid() {
    for (let row = 1; row < blockCountBaseRow + 1; row++) {
        let left = calculateLeftFirstBlock(row);
        let top = calculateTop(row);
        for (let j = 1; j < row + 1; j++) {
            addBlock(left, top);
            left += blockWidth;
        }
    }
}

function addBlock(left, top) {
    let drawingSurface = document.getElementById("drawingSurface");
    drawingSurface.innerHTML += '<div style="' +
        'position:absolute;' +
        'left:' + left + 'px;' +
        'top:' + top + 'px;' +
        'width:' + blockWidth + 'px;' +
        'height:' + blockHeight + 'px;' +
        'border:1px solid black; ' +
        'background:#DDD;">' +
        '</div>';
}

function calculateLeftFirstBlock(row) {
    return drawSurfaceCenter - blockOffset * row;
}

function calculateTop(row) {
    return (row - 1) * blockHeight;
}
```